# expects parameter xx, which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[image]

[image]

dropdownlist contain sname
by selecting item from dropdownlist,i want to display sname,scode,time,price in the data adapter. using parameter @sname
please help by write a stored procedure with parameter.

source code-

```
cn.Open(); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_selectstockname", cn); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()); 
da.Fill(ds);
```

SP :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_selectstockname]
(
     @sname varchar(50)
) 
as begin 
select 
      stocktbl.sname, stocktbl.scode,stockdetails.[time],stockdetails.price 
from 
      stocktbl 
      join stockdetails on stockdetails.scode=stocktbl.scode 
where 
      stocktbl.sname = @sname
end
```

Comment: show some of your code

Comment: What are values in dropdown ? pictures showing database data

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [this page on _How to ask a question_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question. Otherwise we will not be able to help you..

Comment: dropdownlist contain sname

Comment: source code-
 cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_selectstockname", cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            da.Fill(ds);

Comment: Please use the "edit" button (under the tags) to add the code into your question.

Comment: @sam don't be lazy bro. what is sql code, are you expecting people to write averything for you?

Comment: @imad i tried,but i am not getting it.

ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_selectstockname](@sname varchar(50))
as begin
select stocktbl.sname, stocktbl.scode,stockdetails.[time],stockdetails.price 
from stocktbl
 join stockdetails on stockdetails.scode=stocktbl.scode 
 where stocktbl.sname (@sname)
 end

Comment: your code looks good. whats the error?

Comment: @imad- error occurs
selectstockname' expects parameter '@sname', which was not supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_selectstockname", cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()); 
da.Fill(ds);
```

and make sure `DropDownList1.SelectedItem` is not null or DBNull.